# Automatic insertion of line break in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to insert line breaks automatically in the middle of a paragraph, by CSS?

```
<div style="background-image: url('52.jpg'); max-width: 638px; min-width: 538px !important; padding: 11px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: 18px; color: #000000; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #C58917;">
<p style="background-image: url('52.jpg'); padding: 0px 20px 11px 18px;">

----- HERE THE TEXT FLOWS -----
<I need line breaks here>
----- HERE THE TEXT FLOWS -----
<I need line breaks here>
----- HERE THE TEXT FLOWS -----

</p>
</div>
```

My background image is of 242px height and looks like this: http://tinypic.com/r/2nvz2c8/7

Now, I need to insert a break, before the image repeats.

**CSS is preferred, but, JavaScript suggestions are also welcome.**

Comment: It's dangerous to mix styling and content. And linebreak is for me content, that's why you can't set it with CSS. Tell us exactly why and what you need it for, visually, and we can perhaps help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You can however define a fixed width to the paragraph, which will make the text wrap.

To clarify: It will not insert a line-break (which is a specific character) but make the text automatically line-break (without an explicit char).

Comment: `<p style="background-image: url('52.jpg'); padding: 0px 20px 11px 18px; width:638px;">`. Your image is 638px wide, thus limit paragraph width to that.

Comment: You should definitely first do some tutorials or how-tos, and experiment a little. This is such a basic question … Also, CSS references.